# Cannot find package in folder vendor in vscode - Golang

Tags: go, package, gopath

I cloned code here: https://github.com/kkdai/line-login-go.

I deployed on heroku and ran successfully. But I get: `cannot find package` on VSCode

[image: cannot find package vscode]

Normally, if I put the project in the `src` directory, and set `GOPATH`, it will not report an error.

But this project doesn't follow that structure, packages are in the `vendor/` directory.

What do I have to do to handle the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try and [use/add go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) to your cloned project (with Go 1.11+, and `GO111MODULE=on` set):

```
go mod init github.com/kkdai/line-login-go
go mod vendor
```

Then you should have all missing dependencies added to your vendor folder.
And you would not even need `GOPATH` anymore.

As seen in [kardianos/govendor/issue 424](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor/issues/424), `go mod` should recognize `vendor/vendor.json` and import the right references previously declared and managed by **`govendor`**.

Comment: I tried it: 
`go mod init go-module`
`go build`
`go mod vendor`

It created files: go.mod, go.sub 
[(image here)](https://i.imgur.com/hM5QAVh.png)


But in the project: https://github.com/kkdai/line-login-go above, I see they manage packages via file: vendor.json

Comment: @NamLêQuý Yes: as in https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5773, do check that the modules fetched by go mod are the same (same tag or same SHA1) as the ones declared by the vendor.json